# Open a Html file inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a post build event to generate some Html file, is there a way I can open it inside my Visual Studio for viewing as last step of my post build event command?

I tried to use `call "my.htm"` and it will open it in external default browser. I also tried to use `devenv` command in post build event, I just got some exception.

Comment: The change ended with `exited with code 9009` message.

Comment: `Devenv /edit [file1[ file2]]` <-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991989.aspx

Comment: If I run this command outside VS post build event it works fine, but once I included it inside post build event it just gave same error code.

Comment: Here is what worked for me: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "C:\DEV2012\EmailSynchTemp\aaa2.txt" But then, devenv waits for this process to end.

Comment: funny but `notepad...` works, `devenv...` and `iexplore...` - not

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and it worked, so you should try this one here

In post-build define full path to your `devenv`. Just `devenv` didn't work

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /Edit "C:\Temp\aaa2.htm"
```

Comment: really interesting, it worked but with a code `exited with code -1`. By the way is it possible to open to view not edit?

Comment: You can use Internet bowser to view